# I can't open "car" library in r

Tags: r

I tried updating r, uninstalling and reinstalling, but I couldn't fix the problem.

This is what it is happening:

```
install.packages("car")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/COMPAQ/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) probando la URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/car_3.0-10.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 1561252 bytes (1.5 MB)
> downloaded 1.5 MB
>
> package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\RtmpymBNDV\downloaded_packages

```
library(car)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in get(Info[i, 1],
> envir = env):  no fue posible abrir el archivo
> 'C:/Users/COMPAQ/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/abind/R/abind.rdb': No
> such file or directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the `abind` package as well (and perhaps other packages as well), which is only listed under Imports in the Description file of the `car` package

```
install.packages("abind")
```

or

```
install.packages("car", dependencies = "Imports")
```

should work.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it